# How to a click function while waiting for an expected condition?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

While waiting for the expected condition can we keep doing something like keep clicking to a search button ?

```
int time_out = 0;   
while (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='searchResults']/p/span")).isDisplayed() &&time_out != 20 )
    {   
        if(!driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='searchResults']/div[1]/div[1]/*")).isDisplayed())
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchItem']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            time_out++;
        }
        else
        {
            //click on the activation code
            driver.findElement(By.xpath((".//*[@id='searchResults']/div[1]/div[1]/*"))).click();
        }
    }
```

I tried this but somehow didn't work.

Comment: Yes but this code is just a duplication of the explicit waits in Selenium: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: Just tried to find a way to keep clicking on a button while waiting for and expected condition but also controlling this not to be more than 60 seconds.